# How should I check for common security vulnerabilities in my php app?

Tags: php, xss, csrf

I start to write php web application (static php) , I made every thing.

But,how should I check for common security vulnerabilities: *SQL injection*, *XSS*, *CSRF* etc in my web application ?

Comment: If it was easy to "check" there wouldn't be vulnerable sites.

Comment: Your best "check" is to add safety measures and hope it will be fine.

Comment: There is the [OWASP Testing Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Testing_Guide_v4_Table_of_Contents) that you may want to study.

Comment: What is 'static PHP'?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, automated vulnerability scanners can not give a guarantee. So you can not trust their results. I will shortly explain what yo have to do in order to secure your PHP application.

**1. Use PDO instead of Native MySQL Library.**

In order to secure your application agains SQL Injection vulnerability which is one of most critical web application vulnerability, you have to use PDO. For instance,

Do NOT do this.

```
<?php
$cal = $_GET["calories"];
mysql_query('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < '.$cal);
?>
```

Do this.

```
<?php
$calories = $_GET['calcalories'];
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

**2. Encode each variable that you will print on client browser**
This is the key of XSS prevention. You should use encoding method before echo/print variables to the browser! There is 3 kind of XSS vulnerability. First one is Reflected XSS, second one is Stored XSS and last one is Dom Based XSS. Please read following link to understand what is XSS and how can your secure your application agains XSS vulnerability. [https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) .Try to explain three of them will take two or three pages! So i will skip this part.

**3. Insecure Direct Object Reference**

Depends on the web application, this vulnerability can be most dangerous one. Because this is not about the PHP or code syntax. This vulnerability appear because of application desing failure and code anatomy. For example;

```
www.gsmfirm.com/invoice/1337 -> It's your invoice for January!
www.gsmfirm.com/invoice/1338 -> It belongs to someone else!
```

Please read the following link. I'm sure you will understand what is the IDOR and what can it cause. http://avsecurity.in/2013/06/nokia-insecure-direct-object-reference/

**4. PHP Object Injection Vulnerability**

Short explanation, do not use **serialize()** function. Use **json_encode** instead of that. If you will have a look following link. You can understand clearly what is Object Injection vulnerabilities. https :// www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection

**5. CSRF**

Cross Site Request Forgery is can be dangerous too. Basically you have to be sure about "Does this request was sent deliberately by the user?" In order to be sure that, you must generate unique key and store it in session for each user and you have to use it as hidden html input inside of html tags. Than you will check that value for each form request. "is it same with stored ?" if not, the request was not send by client with deliberately.

**6. Broken Authentication and Session Management**

Basically, there is two type of vulnerability. **Session Fixation** and **Session Prediction** . 
In order to be secure against Session Fixation, you have to regenerate session key after successfully logged in. Also you have to use HTTP Header Cookie parameter to carry session key instead of GET parameter.

Session Prediction is weakness about session key generation algorithms. Use complex key generation method to generate unpredictable key. And please do not try to develop your own generation or encryption algorithms.

PS: I couldnt post more than 2 links because of reputation point. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Arachni Scanner](http://www.arachni-scanner.com/). It's an open source tool having both web & cli interface.

Answer (score 0):

I found a company that does it, but I haven't tried them:
http://lp.checkmarx.com/php-code-security

Here are some tips: 
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-helpful-tips-for-creating-secure-php-applications--net-2260

Answer (score 0):

- If there is user authentication then you should check that, current logged in user is not able to access any other data that is not related to him. Means current user has 3 entry from customers table then he should able to access only those 3 entries.
- If you are using framework then they have implemented many security features. For example in Zend Framework Form Elements is able to add csrf in form. So, within given time form should be submitted and csrf key will be verified in back end automatically.
- Most framework gives htmlescapers. So, by using that you can avoid xss at some good level. For static/core php code you should use htmlentities for avoiding extra unwanted characters.